# Stretch image according to the content css

Tags: css, stretch

How to stretch image according to it's content horizontally with css.
[image]

```
//html code

        <style>
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}


    #cont {
    width:100%;
    height:125px;

    background-color:#1ea1de;
    }

    .logo {
        height:100px;
        width:300px;
        background: url(logo3.png) no-repeat;
        margin-top:-105px;
    }
    #liniq {
        height:2.5px;
        width:100%;
        background-color: #b5babc;
        margin-top:5px;
    }
    #levo {
        background: url(levo.gif) no-repeat;
        width:64px;
        height:104px;
        margin-left:280px;
        margin-top:-170px;

    }
    #middle {
        background:url(middle.gif) repeat-x;
        height:41px;
        margin-top:-62px;
        margin-left:321px;
        border:1px solid red;
        overflow:hidden;

    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="cont"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div id="liniq"></div>

<div id="buttons">

<div id="levo"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it don't stretch according to the content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't understand the picture but it seems you're trying to stretch a background-image, which is impossible without using CSS3 property [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size).

Anyway you can place your image in html appliying `width:100%`, its height will automatically be resized.

(And `width:100%` is useless for block elements)